# right way to store collection in db on mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, sails.js

Is it `model.create()` or `.save()` or `.insert()`. I have seen tutorials on web using `.create` on express and sails app . but I haven't seen official document on mongoDB to use `.create()` but people are using it on CRUD App.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is of remarkably low quality, demonstrates no effort, and would see trivial google searches replaced by human beings.

Comment: @AluanHaddad , the users who uses stackoverflow , I think they already did search on google. can you provide me links for the same?

Comment: That is my point. Why shouldn't you do that yourself?

Comment: @AluanHaddad, Brother I already did , As I am learning stuff so I need to get some answers , thats why i asked questions . and I am confused on what is right way to use . I think Stack overflow is for getting help from members

Comment: Yes. You can improve your question by using proper formatting, using complete sentences, adding the code you have attempted to write to the question (no images), and explaining what outcome you are trying to achieve and how your current code (as posted) does not meet that requirement.

Comment: More information is available. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks @AluanHaddad . I will first read and ask proper question with more details .

Answer (score 0):

while aluan Haddad has a valid point, you mentioned that you looked through the mongoDB docs, which is why I'm answering and not flagging the question.

`save()` is a model instance property. Basically, when you change something in your mongoDB data, whether you're entering a new document or editing an existing one, the changes are not done to the database until you call the `save()` function on the model.

`create()` is a property of the Model. you can use it to create a new document by calling the Model property `create()` and passing in the document you want to add as the first parameter: `Model.create({/*your object*/}, function(err, createdObject){/*your callback*/})`.

you can see both of these used [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html).

i formatted the code as i did because your question included the tags mongoose and node.js

Comment: I just read about waterline and mongoose being ORMs . In sails I used destroy() and in express i used remove() . Do I have to learn about collections for both the ORMs . or just MongoDB default model collection will work? I am sorry if I sound weird.